# Multiselect drop down in bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used this [plugin](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) for multiselect and below is my code. Only button is shown. The dropdown doesn't show up and I have been failing to find where it goes wrong. Please suggest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Form</title>

    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettify.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prettify.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="form1" class="form-horizontal" action="http://blahblah/blah/detr.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="get">
<div class="component">
<div class="form-group">

        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;">
                <img src="img/img.png" alt="Form" />
                <h2>Form </h2>
                <br />
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectmultiple">Items</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
            <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
            <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
            <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
            <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
            <option value="onions">Onions</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.multiselect').multiselect();
  });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your all `jQuery` libraries linked correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you load bootstrap before jquery. You must load firstly the jquery library. Change the order of script load from head tag:

from:

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  <!-- put it below-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

change to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```